# HTML и body на весь экран на мобильных устройствах

Tags: css, вёрстка, google-chrome, iphone

В браузере Google Chrome использую симуляцию IPhone5. Необходимо, чтобы теги `<html>` и `<body>` занимали весь экран. На некоторых мобильных устройствах так и происходит. Но не на всех. Разрешение на IPhone5 - 320x568. Ширина и высота `<html>` и `<body>` также - 320px и 568px. Но в действительности размеры тегов меньше. Полагаю, это связано  с аппаратным и референсным пикселем.

PS. Хочется сохранить возможность появления полос прокрутки.

`html, body{overflow-x: hidden;}` - не работает

```
html{
 min-width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
}

body{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Как заставить `<html>` и `<body>` занимать всю доступную область вне зависимости от устройства?

**EDIT1**

Отступы обнуляю всегда так:

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: а для body задать высоту и ширину и так же обнулить внешний и внутренние отступы пробовали ?

Comment: Отступы итак обнулены. Задание ширины и высоты 100% не дает результат.

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/full/VXdgEm/  смотри с мобильного ...на весь экран же?

Comment: Да, но почему у меня не на весь?